# Using tkz-berge with other tikz packages loading order

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, tikz-qtree, tkz-collection

I use the standalone package to preview my tikz pictures without compiling a full document. So the preamble contains all the packages I use. I get an error for most of the  \gr* macro of the tkz-berge package:

> Use of @edge doesn't match its definition.
> \Edge [#1]->@edge [
> #1]
> l.58    \grPrism[RA=6,RB=3]{4}
> %
> ?

The MWE is the following (short code coming from the manual tkz-Berge.sty v2.7c, p. 45, but long preamble)

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}  %% for 3dplot functionality
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   % for parametric function gnu-plot
\usepackage{tkz-berge} %graph package has to be loaded after tikz-qtree package
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
%\usepackage{tkz-berge} %graph package has to be loaded after tikz-qtree package
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge} %graph package has to be loaded after tikz-qtree package
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{
arrows,
arrows.meta,
automata,
backgrounds,
calc,
decorations,
decorations.footprints,
decorations.fractals,
decorations.markings,
decorations.pathmorphing,
decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.shapes,
decorations.text,
external,
fit,
intersections,
math,
matrix,
patterns,
petri,
plotmarks,
positioning,
shadows,
shapes,
shapes.arrows,
shapes.callouts,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.misc,
shapes.multipart,
shapes.symbols,
%snakes,
topaths,
turtle
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\grPrism[RA=6,RB=3]{4}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loading order of the packages is the solution: commenting out the 5th line of the MWE

> \usepackage{tkz-berge} %graph package has to be loaded after tikz-qtree package

and commenting it back in at the 7th line solve the problem. In fact the document class is not relevant, same error happens with the article class. Checking the preamble is the solution.